# mv command. Files cannot be found and disappeared?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I used the following command for the purpose of moving several torrent files in a given folder to a subfolder (TorrentFiles).

Command : sudo mv **/*.torrent ./TorrentFiles

So, all .torrent files should have been moved to TorrentFiles subdirectory.

Now, I can't find the files anywhere.

I have been looking in quite a few places, and have run some various commands that have been suggested on some related forum posts. But nothing has worked for me so far.

Distro : Ubuntu

Comment: `updatedb && mlocate torrent` but also is globstar enabled in your shell? `shopt | grep globstar`

Comment: Let me guess, you have a _file_ `TorrentFiles` now though?

Comment: Thanks everyone. The second command says globstar is off. the updatedb command does not work. Sorry, I'm just really new to Linux (trying to make the transition). I actually don't seem to have a TorrentFiles file. I did sudo nano TorrentFiles in my dir and an empty text file was opened. I generally scrolled through my files and can't seem to locate anything. Should my command not have worked as intended?